# Is there (should there be) an easy way to get the URL of an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

I was looking for a way to shim the `Object.create()` functionality into IE8, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020265/object-create-not-supported-in-ie8) that fit my problem exactly. I gave the accepted answer a try, and it worked perfectly.

I want to have this as a part of a JavaScript utility library that I'll port from project to project, and wanted to cite the answer in my source code so that it could be referenced if one of my coworkers has a question about what the function is for.

Unfortunately, the only way I could find to get the URL of the answer (in case the accepted-ness get changed) was to go to the person's profile, and look through their answers until I found the one, and copy that URL.

I got lucky in that it was the 2nd answer in their list as sorted by votes, but I can't imagine trying to find the answer in the list if it was Jon Skeet (or someone similar).

Did I completely miss an easier way to get that answer's URL? If there is no easier way, could we add a simple link to each answer so that it can be found immediately?

Comment: There is a share link right below each question/answer - that gives the direct path to any post.

Comment: Ugh, so I am an idiot. Should I delete this question, or leave it for any other noobs?

Comment: @krillgar, for maximum helpness to future noobs, you can self-answer it.

Comment: I'll give @bluefeet a few minutes to answer it if they would so choose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "share" link will give you a URL, but it's one of those nasty short URLs - *and* it contains your user ID. There *might* be situations where you don't want to put that in source control...

However, if you actually *follow* that short link, you'll get the full URL, complete with the slug generated from the question's title - this is much nicer to look at and doesn't contain any identifying information. Therefore, I'm in the habit of just Ctrl+clicking the "share" link to open the URL in a new tab, then switching to that tab and copying the full URL from the address bar.

YMMV, of course.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for exemplifying the reason for the delay in being able to accept an answer.

Comment: If you are fine with the short URL, just remove the last slash and number for protecting the guilty party. (No promoter-badge for you though...)

Comment: Is there a way for us to see statistics on how often one of our shared links is clicked? I know you guys use it for badges, but it'd be nice to see on our side as well.

Comment: Not unless you count badges, @george

Comment: @Deduplicator: Announcer badge; Promoter is for bounties :)

Comment: @Wooble: Damn, must study up on those badges some more... Still, my point stands.

Answer (score 7):

There is a share link that is available under each question/answer, just use this to get the URL to any specific post.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. I've seen it before, but never used it, and didn't think of it. I'm glad to see that I am an idiot. ;)

Comment: Whenever I want to share an answer via chat, I will find id of the answer  and then will take the link of the page to form the link. I never noticed this easy way!!!