# Can the 'share' links on questions/answers include the question title slug in the URL?

Tags: feature-request, sharing

Related, but different:

> [Why does the URL from the "share" links contain the ID of the user who is sharing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277769/31668)
>
> [Is there (should there be) an easy way to get the URL of an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271478/31668)

When I go to a question, let's say [ASP.NET vNext is host agnostic, what does it deeply mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431750/asp-net-vnext-is-host-agnostic-what-does-it-deeply-mean), it has a nice slug. The slug is very helpful because it helps the person seeing the URL have some idea of what question is being linked to.

When I use the "share" button for that same question I get [ASP.NET vNext is host agnostic, what does it deeply mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25431750/31668), which of course ultimately redirects to the question (after potentially giving me "fake internet points or badges"!).

I'd like to have a "share" link that both gives me fake internet points/badges, but *also* has a slug in it. That is, something like `https://stackoverflow.com/q/25431750/31668/asp-net-vnext-is-host-agnostic-what-does-it-deeply-mean`.

Answer (score 1):

I also think it would be a noticeable improvement in usability (by virtue of users getting a gist of the linked question's title without having to follow the link).

Experimenting, here's the original link I get after pressing "share":

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274
```

[Can the 'share' links on questions/answers include the question title slug in the URL?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274)

Directly appending the tail of the URL currently **doesn't** work, giving "Page not found":

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274/can-the-share-links-on-questions-answers-include-the-question-title-slug-in-th
```

[Can the 'share' links on questions/answers include the question title slug in the URL?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274/can-the-share-links-on-questions-answers-include-the-question-title-slug-in-th)

However, the following **does** work:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274/?can-the-share-links-on-questions-answers-include-the-question-title-slug-in-th
```

[Can the 'share' links on questions/answers include the question title slug in the URL?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274/?can-the-share-links-on-questions-answers-include-the-question-title-slug-in-th)

And so does this:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274#can-the-share-links-on-questions-answers-include-the-question-title-slug-in-th
```

[Can the 'share' links on questions/answers include the question title slug in the URL?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/1143274#can-the-share-links-on-questions-answers-include-the-question-title-slug-in-th)

Of course, the query or anchor string can be anything. It seems to just be ignored.

So the solution in the meantime is to copy+paste the suffix string manually. Automating (might not save a lot of time, but is great for morale) is easy too. For example, on Windows one can write a few lines of AutoHotkey code (e.g. hooking RightCtrl+C when copying the *share* URL).

Comment: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287411/can-the-share-links-on-questions-answers-include-the-question-title-slug-in-th/1143274` works, though.

Comment: @ale but I doubt it will count as a referral (*potentially giving me "fake internet points or badges"!*).