# Can instructions for linking to a specific answer be made easier to find?

Tags: feature-request

I want to link to a specific answer on a question thread. I know it's possible, because I see such links virtually everywhere yet I see no obvious mechanism.

I search the site for 'link to a specific answer'. Nothing shows up. A similar search of 'help center' yields nothing. Finally I discover 'meta' and come here. Only after typing the title to this post do I see something that might be relevant: *[Citation for (linking to) answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316496/2121227)*

After reading it, the answer is obvious, but I'm astounded that 'Linking to an answer' isn't an FAQ item and that none of the top 10 results from that phrase even mention the word citation (a clue to a word that may have results) much less mention a 'share' button.

The problem is, it's not even a button. I have 'underline links' set to 'always' on my browser and those 'buttons' are not underlined or marked in any way as something that might be clickable. Also, the text is so subdued it looks like its greyed out (inactive) or simply metadata.

Basically I'm saying that these factors work together to make noticing the button at all much less realizing its purpose to be far less likely than people who already know where it is and what it does might think and something as simple as an appropriately titled FAQ entry might get more hits than you think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: I guess you didn't find the "edit" link, either. That one is covered in the [tour].

Comment: Even if I do think to float over the 'share' word.  'short permalink' is esoteric lingo that means nothing to me.  It doesn't somehow translate to "this will generate a URL to this answer".

Comment: Hmm, "permalink" seems like [pretty common jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink), especially for "professional and enthusiast programmers". I'm not a web programmer by any stretch of the imagination, and I knew what it meant. The name itself seems pretty descriptive. Arguably, "URL" is equally as esoteric/jargon as "link", so it's only the "perma-" part that's confusing? That's there to emphasize the fact that, although the URL is a short one, it won't decay over time and eventually become invalid like most other shortened URLs in existence.

Comment: Aside from the possible matter of changing the hover text, I'm not convinced that adding this question to the [meta-tag:faq] would be all that helpful. In my experience, users don't look there. Did you look there? If you searched Meta for "link to specific answer" (which is about all we can ask), and nothing showed up, then *that's* the real problem, and that's eminently fixable—we just need to tweak the wording of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271478/) (and/or a couple of others) to ensure that they *do* show up for this obvious search query.

Answer (score -4):

FAQs are for Frequently Asked Questions.

This isn't a frequently asked question.  It's a very rarely asked question.  Hence it doesn't make sense for it to be in the FAQ.

Comment: So you're saying you actually have statistics on how many times a search for 'link to a specific answer' or variations there of are made and know that it's rare for anyone to look?
IOW by what mechanism are you determining that users don't either simply give up or find someone they can ask in person rather than go thru the embarrassment of publishing a question - knowing full well that the functionality exists and they simply could not spot the mechanism? 
How many people would have the guts to admit they couldn't find it - especially given the treatment they get here!!!!

Comment: @bielawski And yet there are dozens of other questions that people ask much more often, despite being much more basic than that.  I'm not saying nobody ever has this question and doesn't ask this on meta, merely that there are *lots* more quesitons that more people have, and that are more important for people to know, than how to create a permalink to an answer.

Comment: So it's a question of priority.  It's nice to know there are many more important questions that people are not going to get answers to either.  If it was easier to write what you did than to write "Creating a link to an existing answer just takes a click on the [cite] button at the bottom of the answer for which you'd like a URL." in a location that 'Help Center Search' can see then maybe my 'feature request' is too narrowly scoped.  I should have suggested "Can answers to 'SO How To' questions be made easier to provide? For example like programing questions."  Then you wouldn't need an FAQ!

Comment: @bielawski But you *were* able to find the answer to the question.  All you had to do was search for it and you found it.  It wasn't in the FAQ, but the meta question exists and was found as soon as you searched for it.  Not every question can go in the FAQ; if you put *every* question in the FAQ then it ceases to be the Frequently Asked Questions, and is instead Infrequently Asked Questions, and it makes finding the Frequently Asked Questions that much harder as they're buried in a bunch of infrequently asked questions.